# Kendo UI with JQuery change template: <input> to readonly or disable

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
  <td role="gridcell">input</td>
  <td role="gridcell">1</td>
  <td role="gridcell">
    <input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 4px">
    <input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="220" style="margin: 4px">
    <input class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 4px">   
    </td>
  <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">
  </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr class="k-alt" role="row">
    <td role="gridcell">input</td>
    <td role="gridcell">2</td><td role="gridcell">
    <input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 4px">
    <input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="59" style="margin: 4px">
    <input class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 4px">
      
    </td>
    </tr>
      
    </tbody>
```

**top was my out put Html**

**Then i using JQuery to change below code to disable or readonly but it didn't work!**

```
<input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="220" style="margin: 4px">
```

**I Try on kendo Ui with JQuery**

```
$("#Txt_test").attr('disabled', true);
```

**and**

```
$("#Txt_test").prop('readonly', true);
```

**and change class**

```
$(".txtBox").attr('disabled', true);
```

**I have change input type="text" same error for me.
also I try**

```
var clearAddGrid = $("#AddGrid").data('kendoGrid');
clearAddGrid.editable = false;
```

**I want achieve like below**

```
if(status==0)
{
    Grid input can edit
}else{
    Grid input can't edit
}
```

**and this is my grid cells**

```
{ field: "txtRealNum", title: "RealNum", width: "40px", template: '<input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 1px" /><input  id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value= #=txtRealNum# style="margin: 4px" /><input  class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 1px" />' },
```

my grid

```
    $("#AddGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: AddGriddataSource,
        selectable: "row",
        scrollable: false,
        columns: AddGridCells,
        change: numberInput,
        pageable: {
            buttonCount: 3,
            messages: GridPageMsg
        },
        height: '100%',
        editable: true
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: please make an example here https://dojo.telerik.com/iBiZuGAc , clone it, and add it to your question then i can help you

Comment: @dev_in_progress hi, did you mean like this https://dojo.telerik.com/EZAYUkoN

Answer (score 2):

So you want to disabled this?

```
<input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="220" style="margin: 4px">
```

Since you are using Kendo UI for jQuery, you can do this:

```
$("#Txt_test").addClass("k-state-disabled");
```

That should do it.

Thanks for the example in the Telerik DOJO. If you want to disable all the `input` text boxes. Add the line below after your Kendo Grid initialization.

```
$(".txtBox1").addClass("k-state-disabled");
```

For your convenience:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/from-table">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="AddGrid" style="height: 100%;" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget">
      <table role="grid" data-role="selectable" class="k-selectable" style="height: auto;">          <colgroup>
        <col style="width:20px">
        <col style="width:20px">
        <col style="width:30px">
        <col style="width:30px">
        <col style="width:20px">
        </colgroup>
        <thead class="k-grid-header" role="rowgroup">
          <tr role="row">
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="txtRawNo" data-title="no" class="k-header">no</th><th role="columnheader" data-field="txtRawName" data-title="Name" class="k-header">name</th>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="txtUnit" data-title="U" class="k-header">U</th>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="txtBookNum" data-title="U" class="k-header">SNUM</th>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="txtTranNum" data-title="NUM" class="k-header">NUM</th>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="txtVersion" data-title="Version" style="display:none" class="k-header">Version</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody role="rowgroup"><tr data-uid="130d7d37-64f4-4f6e-98ca-fb2293e8d6ab" role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">11007109-2</td><td role="gridcell">SB 1kg*10</td>
          <td role="gridcell">1000g</td><td role="gridcell">818</td>
          <td role="gridcell"><input id="Del" class="Del1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 1px">
            <input id="Txt_test1" class="txtBox1" type="textbox" value="5" style="margin: 4px"><input id="plus" class="plus1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 1px">
          </td>
          <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">2021-06-02T15:08:00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="85651f08-df24-40b2-ae05-94123efb3125" role="row">
            <td role="gridcell">11094184</td><td role="gridcell">MS 1kg*10</td>
            <td role="gridcell">1000g</td>
            <td role="gridcell">801</td>
            <td role="gridcell">
              <input id="Del" class="Del1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 1px">
              <input id="Txt_test1" class="txtBox1" type="textbox" value="15" style="margin: 4px"><input id="plus" class="plus1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 1px"></td>
            <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">2021-06-03T11:24:00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget" data-role="pager">
        <a href="#" title="Go to the first page" class="k-link k-pager-nav k-pager-first k-state-disabled" data-page="1" tabindex="-1">
          <span class="k-icon k-i-seek-w">Go to the first page</span>
        </a><a href="#" title="Go to the previous page" class="k-link k-pager-nav k-state-disabled" data-page="1" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-w">Go to the previous page</span></a>
        <ul class="k-pager-numbers k-reset">
          <li><span class="k-state-selected">1</span></li></ul>
        <a href="#" title="Go to the next page" class="k-link k-pager-nav k-state-disabled" data-page="1" tabindex="-1">
          <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e">Go to the next page</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Go to the last page" class="k-link k-pager-nav k-pager-last k-state-disabled" data-page="1" tabindex="-1">
          <span class="k-icon k-i-seek-e">Go to the last page</span></a>
        <span class="k-pager-info k-label">page1-2，total 2</span></div></div>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                selectable: "row",
                height: 550,
                sortable: true,
                editable: true
            });
          
            $(".txtBox1").addClass("k-state-disabled"); // comment/uncomment to see the outcome
        });    
     
    </script>
</div>

    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also try `$(".txtBox").addClass("k-state-disabled");`

Comment: But I tap F12 and change class to `class="k-state-disabled"` it can work

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say? What exactly do you want to happen with respect to the example in the Telerik DOJO?

Comment: Sorry I'm Idiot because ,When I didn't get Grid i add this `$(".txtBox").addClass("k-state-disabled");` so i didn't work ......      then i try again it work for me

Comment: but if i change the page it will Invalidation

Answer (score 1):

Make all inputs with class "txtBox" as kendo component and disable it

```
$(".txtBox1").kendoTextBox({
       enable: false
});
```

Based on upper example: [Disable inputs](https://dojo.telerik.com/ACojoJeH)

Comment: Thanks you share the ans i will try it

Comment: i cant use this function i see my project is using   Kendo UI v2014.2.903

Comment: hi @dev_in_progress on this example which kendo ui version did you use

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code to this :

```
$("#Txt_test").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```